# Cannot unbox as a 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>'

Tags: c#

I have gird view which allows to select one of the items. This property `SelectedItem` is of type object. However it is `KeyValuePair<MyObject1, MyObject2>`, where `MyObject2` may be null and quite often is `null`. When I want to use this selected object and I try to cast that object into `KeyValuePair<MyObject1, MyObject2>` and `MyObject2` is `null`, I get `InvalidCastException`.

```
a
{[StrangerParty.DataAccess.Models.Actor,]}
(KeyValuePair<Actor, Role>)a
Cannot unbox 'a' as a 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<StrangerParty.DataAccess.Models.Actor,StrangerParty.DataAccess.Models.Role>'
```

So it is possible to cast this object `{[MyObject1, ]}` to `KeyValuePair<MyObject1, MyObject2>` or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What does `a?.GetType().ToString()` give? The error message is not helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: You must type `a.GetType().ToString()` and report here what you get! Currently I see a curly brace `{` followed by a square bracket `[` but it does not tell me exactly what you have. It could be a `KeyValuePair<,>` inside some other object (the `{`...`}`).